# jQuery toggle keeps repeating

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, toggle

I'm pretty new to jQuery, but seemed like it's a no-brainer. Just the same, I can't figure it out.
I'm trying to toggle between two animation functions, but when function two completes, it goes ahead and calls function one as well.

```
function toggleThis(){
    $("#navSliderArrow").toggle(function() {       
        $(this).animate({ marginLeft: '235' }, 500);
        $("#sliderArrow").attr("src", "images/hide_nav.gif");
    }, function() {       
        $(this).animate({ marginLeft: '0' }, 500);
        $("#sliderArrow").attr("src", "images/show_nav.gif");
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
~gyz

Comment: As far as I know, `.toggle` has only one callback function. Not sure what happens when you have 2 functions like that.. Anyways, What are you trying to achive here?

Comment: Binding this function to a click event will virtually click the button twice, once for the click and once for the toggle. This is why you see  it slide both directions.

Comment: Please include your relevant HTML so we can know more about what this function is really doing.

Answer (score 1):

From my comment earlier,

> As far as I know, .toggle has only one callback function. Not sure
>   what happens when you have 2 functions like that.. Anyways, What are
>   you trying to achive here?

Read more [.toggle API doc](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

I assume that you are trying to show and hide `onclick` of `#sliderArrow`. If so then try below,

```
   $(function () {
       var $slideArrow = $("#sliderArrow");
       var $navSlideArrow = $('#navSliderArrow');
       $slideArrow.on ('click', function () {              
          if ($slideArrow.attr('src').indexOf('show') >= 0) {
                $navSlideArrow.animate({ marginLeft: '235' }, 500);
                $slideArrow.attr("src", "images/hide_nav.gif");
          } else {
                $navSlideArrow.animate({ marginLeft: '0' }, 500);
                $slideArrow.attr("src", "images/show_nav.gif");
          }
       });
   });
```

Comment: No, this seems to have the same problem, only instead of repeating itself only once, it repeats itself once for every time clicked (nothing the first click, once the second click,twice the third click, etc). Maybe ignore the image swap for now - all I'm trying to do is use the same clickable div to move its position to the left on first click, then to the right on the second one.

Comment: The funny thing is, my original code works fine if you throw in a non-existent function, like $(this).harumph(); to break the function. Too bad it throws up an error.

Answer (score 0):

Quote OP:

> "What am I doing wrong?"

As per [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), your syntax is wrong.  You cannot have two callback functions inside `toggle()`.

> .toggle( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] )
>
> - **duration**  - A string or number determining how long the animation will run.
> - **easing**  - A string indicating which easing function to use for the transition.
> - **callback** - A function to call once the animation is complete.

---

**EDIT:**

After reading the other answers, I see that there is [another version of jQuery `toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)...

http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

> .toggle( handler(eventObject), handler(eventObject) [,handler(eventObject)] )
>
> - **handler(eventObject)** - A function to execute every even time the element is clicked.
> - **handler(eventObject)** - A function to execute every odd time the element is clicked.
> - **handler(eventObject)** - Additional handlers to cycle through after clicks.

Properly implemented, your jQuery should look like *something like* this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#navSliderArrow").toggle(
        function() {       
            $(this).animate({ marginLeft: '235' }, 500);
            $("#sliderArrow").attr("src", "images/hide_nav.gif");
        },
        function() {       
            $(this).animate({ marginLeft: '0' }, 500);
            $("#sliderArrow").attr("src", "images/show_nav.gif");
        }
    );
});
```

And with jQuery, there is absolutely **no need for any inline JavaScript** like `<a href="#" onclick="togglethis()">`.  Your HTML should look *something like*...

```
<a href="#" id="navSliderArrow">
```

I only say "something like" that since your HTML is not included in your OP and I have no idea what your target elements are supposed to be.

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VGYyf/)

Comment: Strange, I got this syntax from another site that suggested it's how you toggle between two functions.
What I'm trying to do, though, is have a div that moves to the right 235px on first click, then back to 0px on the next click, ad nauseum.
Seems like pretty beginner stuff, but, well, that's me.

Comment: Whoops, I guess I should have added @Sparky672 to that last post.

Comment: @gyzhor,  You don't need the `@user` when responding to the user's own answer or question.  Also see my edited answer and include more HTML in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an event handler version of .toggle() - http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

The toggle event handler binds the click method itself, so you just need to directly perform the animation:

```
$("#navSliderArrow").toggle(
    function() {       
        $(this).animate({ marginLeft: '235' }, 500);
        $("#sliderArrow").attr("src", "images/hide_nav.gif");
    }, 
    function() {       
        $(this).animate({ marginLeft: '0' }, 500);
        $("#sliderArrow").attr("src", "images/show_nav.gif");
    }
);
```

Comment: So this is essentially the same as what I originally posted, except outside of the togglethis() function? I don't seem to get any functionality when i place this outside the original function.

Comment: Did you bind the original function to a click event? Can you post more code?

Comment: Whoops - just saw your fiddle now. Something must be wrong elsewhere. Let me check ...

Comment: I'm using <a href="#" onclick="togglethis()"><img src="images/hide_nav.gif" /></a> as my click event. This calls it, but it still has the repetition problem I mentioned before.

Comment: @gyzhor, then that fully explains what you're doing wrong and what you left out of your original OP.  You do **not** need inline JavaScript when you bind an event.  In other words, if you bind a click event to an object with jQuery, you do **not** also use `onclick=` within the `<a>`.

Comment: Since you are binding the onclick event to the function, you are getting two events for every click of the anchor tag.  The code inside of your togglethis function is actually adding another toggle event every time you click the link.  To make this work as you expect, you have to remove the onclick event handler after the first time togglethis is called, then the toggle event will handle all of the clicks after that.  [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/styson/SEjya/2/)

Comment: There is no need for `onclick=` with jQuery, especially when you remove the `onclick` with a `.removeAttr('onclick')` anyway.  Also, there is a section made just for JavaScript in jsFiddle.

Comment: I understand that - just trying to show (using gyzhor's code) what is going on.

Comment: I knew about the javascript section - hadn't figured out how to put it in the head section (using [no wrap (head)]) until now. Thanks.

Comment: There is no need for a `head` section in jsFiddle since everything is already included in the "Add Resources", JavaScript, and CSS sections.

Comment: Thanks, the both of you, this has been extremely helpful.  I finally ended up with this: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gyzhor/zksac/2/).  It works perfectly in the fiddle, but still doesn't work in my full project. I don't want to bother you with a lot of extraneous code, but for some reason, it won't work with anything other than `$(document).click`, which I don't want for obvious reasons. I'll keep prodding at it, though. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is good practice to tag the answer to your question that resolves the issue. Good luck on your quest.